# The Select All and Paste menu in the TextField KivyMD field appears for a second and disappears

Tags: python, kivy

I have a small app with input fields and A toolbar, when I tap and hold my finger in the input field, the Select All and Paste menu appears for a second and disappears. I test everything not on the emulator, but on my phone.

[full KV file](https://gist.github.com/Neizvestnyj/3ea0ef80a423579915e14a570ac492f6)

Answer (score 0):

Try `buildozer android clen`

```
requirements = kivy==cf88ec5,kivymd,boto3,botocore,openssl,pyjnius,ecdsa,bcrypt,cryptography,paramiko,dateutil,urllib3,jmespath,PyNaCl,android
```